# irssi dcc stats on channel

Tags: perl, irssi

I made my first irssi perl script, but it doesn't work.  I don't understand why not.

When I type `!dccstat` on the channel, my home PC just responds with all DCC connections, like when I type `/dcc stat` on irssi.

```
use Irssi;

use vars qw($VERSION %IRSSI);

$VERSION = "1.0";
%IRSSI = (
Test
);

sub event_privmsg {
my ($server, $data, $nick, $mask) =@_;
my ($target, $text) = $data =~ /^(\S*)\s:(.*)/;
        return if ( $text !~ /^!dccstat$/i );
if ($text =~ /^!dccstat$/ ) {
        my $dcc = dccs();
        $server->command ( "msg $target $dcc" )
    }
}

Irssi::signal_add('event privmsg', 'event_privmsg');
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem may be the `dccs()` command itself, it's not recognized in my Irssi v0.8.15, so I used `Irssi::Irc::dccs()`. It returns **the array** of dcc connections, so it won't (pardon my sarcasm) "magically" turn into string of current dccs status, as "/dcc list" (you used "/dcc stat" term which i beleive is either a mistake or a command of a script which is unknown to me). You need to loop through the array of dccs and pick up the all the data you want. A sketchy (but working) code is given below, so you could use it as a template. Have fun with Irssi scripts.

```
use Irssi;

use vars qw($VERSION %IRSSI);

$VERSION = "1.0";
%IRSSI = (
Test
);

sub event_privmsg {
    my ($server, $data, $nick, $mask) =@_;
    my ($target, $text) = $data =~ /^(\S*)\s:(.*)/;
    return if ( $text !~ /^!dccstat$/i ); # this line could be removed as the next one checks for the same
    if ($text =~ /^!dccstat$/ ) {
        # get array of dccs and store it in @dccs
        my @dccs = Irssi::Irc::dccs();
        # iterate through array
        foreach my $dcc (@dccs) {
            # get type of dcc (SEND, GET or CHAT)
            my $type = $dcc->{type};
            # process only SEND and GET types
            if ($type eq "SEND" || $type eq "GET") {
                my $filename = $dcc->{arg};   # name of file            
                my $nickname = $dcc->{nick};  # nickname of sender/receiver
                my $filesize = $dcc->{size};  # size of file in bytes
                my $transfered = $dcc->{transfd}; # bytes transfered so far

                # you probably want to format file size and bytes transfered nicely, i'll leave it to you
                $server->command("msg $target nick: $nickname type: $type file: $filename size: $filesize transfered: $transfered");
            }
        }
    }
}

Irssi::signal_add('event privmsg', 'event_privmsg');
```

Also, you use "event privmsg" which triggers also for (surprise!) private messages, not only channel ones, yet it works for those too (the response would be sent as a private message to the user). If it's not desired, i suggest use of "message public" signal, as below:

```
# ..

sub event_message_public {
    my ($server, $msg, $nick, $mask, $target) = @_;

    # .. the rest of code

}

Irssi::signal_add("message public", event_message_public);
```